# Bootstrap: can't close modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

i am testing this [website](http://testing.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) and as you can see is a "fullpage" website.

In the first page i have button connected to a Modal but when is open is not possible to closed it anymore and i realized that it fit the ENTIRE website height and not the actual page.

How can i fix it?

The website is builted using Wordpress + Bootstrap and i used the "[Fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)" method

Comment: Seems to open up **behind** the overlay, that's why the click doesn't reach the modal DOM element.

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue to me. Use the inspector and play with some z-index styles.

Comment: <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close 'X' button at top-right of your modal is behind an invisible, fixed positioned element running along the top, i.e. this:

```
<div class="bt-menu-control-sticky">
```

In core.css:

```
.bt-menu-control-sticky{z-index:999999;}
```

You will need to make your modal have a higher z-index value than this, whatever you set it to, or change the positioning of the modal. I can see that your close button is working if this problem element is set to `z-index: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Attatch a click handler to the body or the X and call

```
$('.modal').modal('hide')
```

This will close all modals so be careful. Use a unique id for the modal